# How to get a value from a vector including a range in Julia

Tags: vector, julia

Coming from `R` I am used to do something like this to get the first element of vector `a`:

```
a <- c(1:3, 5)
a[1]
[1] 1
```

H can I get the `1` in `Julia`? The first element of `a` is now a `range`.

```
a = [1:3, 5]
a[1]
1-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}:
 1:3
```

Comment: You might want to consider switching the accepted answer to Stefan's response. While Sam's response does give you the element you are after, the use of `collect` is unnecessary and is actually a very common performance "gotcha" in Julia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The core problem here is that `c(1:3, 5)` in R and `[1:3, 5]` in Julia do not do the same thing. The R code concatenates a vector with an integer producing a vector of four integers:

```
> c(1:3, 5)
[1] 1 2 3 5
```

The Julia code constructs a two-element vector whose elements are the range `1:3` and the integer `5`:

```
julia> [1:3, 5]
2-element Vector{Any}:
  1:3
 5

julia> map(typeof, ans)
2-element Vector{DataType}:
 UnitRange{Int64}
 Int64
```

This vector has element type `Any` because there's no smaller useful common supertype of a range and an integer. If you want to concatenate `1:3` and `5` together into a vector you can use `;` inside of the brackets instead of `,`:

```
julia> a = [1:3; 5]
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 5
```

Once you've defined `a` correctly, you can get its first element with `a[1]` just like in R. In general inside of square brackets in Julia:

- Comma (`,`) is only for constructing vectors of the exact elements given, much like in Python, Ruby, Perl or JavaScript.
- If you want block concatenation like in R or Matlab, then you need to use semicolons/newlines (`;` or `\n`) for vertical concatenation and spaces for horizontal concatenation.

The given example of `[1:3; 5]` is a very simple instance of block concatenation, but there are significantly more complex ones possible. Here's a fancy example of constructing a block matrix:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> A = rand(2, 3)
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.895017  0.442896  0.0488714
 0.750572  0.797464  0.765322

julia> [A' I
        0I A]
5×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.895017   0.750572  1.0       0.0       0.0
 0.442896   0.797464  0.0       1.0       0.0
 0.0488714  0.765322  0.0       0.0       1.0
 0.0        0.0       0.895017  0.442896  0.0488714
 0.0        0.0       0.750572  0.797464  0.765322
```

Apologies for StackOverflow's lousy syntax highlighting here: it seems to get confused by the postfix `'`, interpreting it as a neverending character literal. To explain this example a bit:

- `A` is a 2×3 random matrix of `Float64` elements
- `A'` is the adjoint (conjugate transpose) of `A`
- `I` is a variable size unit diagonal operator
- `0I` is similar but the diagonal scalar is zero

These are concatenated together to form a single 5×5 matrix of `Float64` elements where the upper left and lower right parts are filled from `A'` and `A`, respectively, while the lower left is filled with zeros and the upper left is filled with the 3×3 identity matrix (i.e. zeros with diagonal ones).

Answer (score 2):

In this case, your a[1] is a UnitRange collection. If you want to access an individual element of it, you can use collect

For example for the first element,

```
collect(a[1])[1]
```

Comment: There is no need to collect. a[1][1] works as well. Although it is good to show that the vector the OP is creating in julia is not equivalent to the one they have in R